# Indexing matrices in matlab

Tags: matlab, eigenvector

So I have a script that I run j times.  The following line produces an error:

`[evec(:,:,j), eval(:,:,j)] = eig(T(:,:,j));`

```
Error using mupadmex
Error in MuPAD command: Cannot compute the explicit
representation of the eigenvalues; use
'numeric::eigenvectors'. [linalg::eigenvectors]

Error in sym/mupadmexnout (line 2080)
        out = mupadmex(fcn,args{:});

Error in sym/eig (line 68)
        [V,D,p] = mupadmexnout('symobj::eigenvectors',A);

Error in SingleLayer (line 86)
[evec(:,:,j), eval(:,:,j)] = eig(T(:,:,j));
```

That is the error message I get.  Am I correct creating 3 "sheets" (not sure how to describe it) like this.  I

Comment: What if you run just `eig(T(:,:,j));`?

Comment: I can run eig(T(:,:,1))

Comment: What is the range of `j`?

Comment: for what I am running, `j=1:3`

Comment: I don't think that this has anything to do with matrix indexing. [This link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/14433) suggests that the problem is probably in your matrix `T`...

Comment: @EitanT is right. This has nothing to do with indexing, but I still wouldn't use a variable called `eval`, which is the same name of an important function.

Comment: What is T? Is it symbolic? Can you give a complete example?

Comment: Well T is a 100 x 100 complex matrix.  It SHOULD NOT be symbolic.  I looked through the matrix and do not see any symbolic variables